# Regex in IF condition in awk

Tags: awk, regular-expression

I have `awk` script file as below. I need to add another condition in the `if` statement to check if the string contains atleast one alphabet. How can I add the extra condition to the present `if` statement?

Required regex condition: `[[ "$1" =~ [A-Za-z] ]]`

```
BEGIN { FS = ";"; counter=0}

{ 
 if ((length($1) != 10 && length($1) != 12))
   { 
    counter++
    print counter, $1;
    if ($counter -gt 2){
        print "Invalid input file";
        exit;
    }    
   }
}
```

I am getting error if I use the same condition which I have posted. How to add the condition?

Comment: See the examples here: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Regexp-Usage

Comment: How do you add it? You are showing us a bash-style if statement. The regex is fine, but the regex is just `[A-Za-z]`. What are you adding to your `awk`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You don't actually show how you add the regex, so I am guessing you are using the same format: `=~ [A-Za-z]`. That won't work. Each language has its own syntax for regex matching. In `awk`, the format is `$target ~ /$regex/`, so `$1 ~ /[A-Za-z]/`.

```
BEGIN { FS = ";"; counter=0}

{ 
 if (length($1) != 10 && length($1) != 12 && $1 ~ /[A-Za-z]/)
   { 
    counter++
    print counter, $1;
    if (counter > 2){
        print "Invalid input file";
        exit;
    }    
   }
}
```

Also, in `awk`, the `$` sign is used to mark *fields*, not *variables*. So `$counter` will be evaluated to the field number of `counter`. If `counter` is `2`, then `$counter` will be the value of the second field. And the `-gt` is  also not an awk thing. Just use `>`.

Comment: Yes. I was using `=~` format.

Comment: Why couldnt you move the condition to be the pattern? `length($1) != 10 && ... && $1 ~ /[A-Za-z]/ { counter++ ... }` seems more « awkish » to me, avoiding some seriously nested braces

Comment: @D.BenKnoble why indeed! I just copy/pasted the OP's code and added the regex. I just didn't realize it was that nested. Thanks!